# elastic bean stalk, django, and wsgipath

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, django-wsgi

I am finding issue with my `WSGIPath` in my django elasticbeanstalk deployment.

my `.ebextensions` folder is in root, my `django.config` file contains the following:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: shofidecksite.wsgi:application
```

now there are a few things what the code should be where `shofidecksite` is.

I have tried the following:

`shofidecksite` which is the name of the django project

`shofidecksite` again, which is the elasticbeanstalk application name

`shofi-env` which is the environment name

I keep getting the error:  `ERROR Your WSGIPath refers to a file that does not exist.`

and I am having a very hard time figuring out what it wants from me.

for the extra giggles and maybe clarity here is a screen shot of my path

[image]

Can anyone add some light to this please

Comment: It should be `shofidecksite.wsgi:application`, so your first attempt is correct. Can you ssh to EB instance and inspect `/var/app/stating` folder if all your files are there? Maybe your .gitignore ignores these files or somehow they are missing from your deployment package.

Comment: Also are you sure you are using EB platform based on Amazon Linux 2? For AL1, the WSGI settings are different.